Wrapping the Tasks Command in a New Environment
I am trying to remap the \task to a new command that can take multiple arguments (noting that \NewTasksEnvironment can be used to change \task to \item, but this is not what I am trying to fix here).
I appreciate that the solution must be more nuanced than the below to maintain compatibility with the various tasks features (e.g. \task* or \task!), but nevertheless, trying to make the below work (if possible):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{xparse}

% Define \itemJ using \NewDocumentCommand
\NewDocumentCommand{\itemJ}{m O{}}{%
    \task #1 \\
    \textit{Solution}:
    #2 
}

\begin{document}

\title{Tasks Package Example with \texttt{NewDocumentCommand}}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section*{Example Task Lists}

\subsection*{Simple Task List with itemJ}
\begin{tasks}
\itemJ{First item}
\itemJ{Second item}
\itemJ{Third item}
\end{tasks}

\subsection*{Task List with Multiple Columns}
\begin{tasks}(3)
\itemJ{First item}
\itemJ{Second item}
\itemJ{Third item}
\itemJ{Fourth item}
\itemJ{Fifth item}
\itemJ{Sixth item}
\end{tasks}

\subsection*{Task List with Custom Labels}
\begin{tasks}[label=\alph*., label-format={\bfseries}](2)
\itemJ{First item}
\itemJ{Second item}
\itemJ{Third item}
\itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{tasks}

\end{document}

Current no tasks print


It seems that \task just acts as a separator, try \begin{tasks}(3) \task {\meaning\task} \end{tasks}, yield a) undefined.

The problem here is that the main tasks environment looks for explicit use of the control sequence \task and use that as a separating delimiter to identify (and manipulate) each task. So, without it, the environment assumes there's no tasks and nothing to do.

The idea is simple: define \itemJ to put its argument into a token list variable. Then use V signature to expand this token list variable first so that the tasks environment could see \task as its item separator.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\itemJ}{m O{}}{%
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \task #1 \\ \textit{Solution:} ~ #2 }
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{harrytasks}
  {
    O{} % optional options
    D(){1} % number of columns
  }
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }
  {
    \harry_task_make:nnV {#1} {#2} \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \harry_task_make:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \begin{tasks}[#1](#2) #3 \end{tasks}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \harry_task_make:nnn {nnV}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\title{Tasks Package Example with \texttt{NewDocumentCommand}}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section*{Example Task Lists}

\begin{harrytasks}
  \itemJ{First item}[This is the solution]
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}(2)
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}[label=\alph*., label-format={\bfseries}](2)
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\end{document}



Stephen, yyds !!!

I believe that the optional argument to the environment should be O{} rather than o

Modified.@egreg

Unreal; lovely solution

This works a charm. Any way we can make \task (or better \item) work within the list for backwards compatibility sake, it doesnt at the moment, e.g.
\begin{harrytasks}(2)
\item abcd
\itemJ{First item}
\itemJ{Second item}
\itemJ{Third item}
\itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}
and Ideally \item just is \itemP{#1}

Also curious, what is the purpose of introducing the variant. Could we not just say when we declare Harry task that it requires a token list: ie harry_task_make:nnV ; I imagine there is a good reason for this, I just don’t know!

The variant is used to change the order of expansion.@Harry

An alternative using the new enumext package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumext}
\begin{document}
\section*{enumext* one columns}

\begin{enumext*}[label=\alph*), save-ans=test,wrap-ans={\emph{Solution:} #1},show-ans=true]
  \item First item \anskey{This is the solution for First item}
  \item Second item \anskey{This is the solution Second item}
  \item Third item \anskey{This is the solution Third item}
\end{enumext*}

\section*{enumext* two columns}

\begin{enumext*}[label=\alph*), columns=2,save-ans=test,wrap-ans={\emph{Solution:} #1},show-ans=true]
  \item First item \anskey{This is the solution for First item}
  \item Second item \anskey{This is the solution Second item}
  \item Third item \anskey{This is the solution Third item}
  \item Fourth item \anskey{This is the solution Fourth item}
\end{enumext*}

\section*{enumext* two columns, other label}

\begin{enumext*}[label=\alph*., font=\bfseries,columns=2,save-ans=test,wrap-ans={\emph{Solution:} #1},show-ans=true]
  \item First item \anskey{This is the solution for First item}
  \item Second item \anskey{This is the solution Second item}
  \item Third item \anskey{This is the solution Third item}
  \item Fourth item \anskey{This is the solution Fourth item}
\end{enumext*}

\section*{Solutions}

\printkeyans*[label=\alph*)]{test}

\end{document}



This looks very promising indeed! Is there an ability to add multiple classes of solutions, e.g.
\anskey{A} and then say \fullSolution{A - The answer is A because of xyz}

The interface it provides does not have that utility, it is designed in another way, you could play with \Scontent and \anskey to achieve what you want, although since it is only a one-level list you can use \anskey{A} and then \ref{test:1} together with \getkayans.
